# Sending email with accented letters like "è" or "à" through PHP

Tags: php, html, email

I  have a string like

```
$mail_sblocco='Il tuo account è stato sbloccato,&lt;br&gt;cordiali saluti.&lt;br&gt;';
```

If I convert the string with 
`$corpomail="<html><body>".htmlspecialchars_decode($mail_sblocco)."</body></html>";`, I see all great in the browser. But in the webmail I see strange characters like "Ã¨".
I'm trying to send this email with php.
The headers are

```
$header="From: example@ex.com\r\n";
$header.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header.= "Content-type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n";
$header.="Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";
```

On the browser I see

```
Il tuo account è stato sbloccato,
cordiali saluti.
```

On the webmail, I see

```
Il tuo account Ã¨ stato sbloccato,
cordiali saluti.
```

How can I fix this?
If you need more informations, tell me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `charset=\"iso-8859-1\"` probably doesn't match your actual accented letter encoding. Neither does `7bit`. See also: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: I solved editing header. These are the new values:
charset=\"utf-8\" and Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable.
Thank you mario